# JSON Vulnerability Protection Filter in Web Api

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have an application in ASP.NET Web Api with AngularJS and I want to resolve the json vulnerability issue. I read the [Phil Haack's article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/).

In the project I want to serialize a class object into JSON format using the JsonConvert class.

I read [Sean Kenny's solution](http://www.seankenny.me/blog/2014/09/28/web-api-and-angularjs-json-vulnerability-protection-filter/), but doesn't work because jsonwriter from json.net library can't serialize an invalid json format.

Can somebody give me a hint or what I can use to obtain a serialized json with string `")]}',\n"` in front the json response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "...make sure that your JSON service always returns its response as a
>   non-array JSON object" - Phil Haack.

Simply return your JSON as an object, not an array. You don't need to prepend those special characters. In other words, if your data is an array, like `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, don't return the array. Instead wrap it in an object and return the object, `{ d: [1, 2, 3, 4] }`.

However, *if you feel really strongly* about prepending those special characters, then just concatenate it. `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` returns a string, so...

`return ")]}',\n" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);`

But, in my opinion, that's unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I will try this as soon as possible. I want to ask something else: what can I use to catch the response before sending it? I've tried to use action filter (OnActionExecuted method) and message handlers (Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync method) but the response it's not json serialized (the type of response is still a class object).

Comment: Do you mean how to catch the _request_ before it is sent to the _server_ or the _response_ before it is sent to the _client_? For more on model binding, have a read [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) and let me know if it helps.